# Does Eloqua Landing Pages support any scripting languages?

Tags: eloqua

new to Eloqua.

I am going to create some landing pages on Eloqua, and it seems like there is any no backend or scripting language to show first name/last name/ or do some backend validation or calculation. Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, there is no backend associated with Eloqua as it is a Cloud based service.

For validations or calculations you could use JavaScript and/or JQuery.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Yes, I will have to use client-side javascript or Jquery for a custom calculator. FYI, Salesforce Marketing Cloud/ExactTarget has backend languages (AMPScript or Server Side JavaScript) even though it's a cloud based service as well.